# Text and div vertical aligning inside a list element

Tags: html, css

I have the following layout:

```
<ul>
    <li>Text
        <div class="task"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PLtFz/). I am having problems aligning the text `Text`. Now it is on the same line as the `div`. I would like to align (vertically) the `Text` to the middle of the `div`. I have tried nesting the `Text` inside a `span` and giving the `span margin-bottom, padding-bottom`, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware of spacing issues with inline-block - http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

http://jsfiddle.net/6AxbH/1/

```
.task {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I am dazed how long I have been stuck on this one! By the way, is it possible to do `vertical-align` pixel by pixel?

Comment: All possible alignements: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align

Comment: Great, I'll read the article as soon as I am done with few other things.

Comment: You can do pixels but is more complex as it starts from the baseline and takes in account the text height (~ font-size) as well. http://jsfiddle.net/6AxbH/16/

Answer (score 0):

```
.task {
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    float:none;
}

ul li {
    text-align:center;
    width:50px;
    display:block;
    list-style:none;
}
```

I just set a width on the LI to match what the size of the box was (then reduced the size of the box to make sure it centered) and applied display:block;text-align:center; to center everything.